# Drupal 7 video support

Tags: drupal, video, drupal-7, html5-video, drupal-modules

On Drupal 7 I want to be be able to:

- Allow users to upload MP4 videos, or link to an external url of an
  MP4 video (not youtube videos, just a video file)
- Display these videos in a HTML 5 video player in an article, with a flash fallback that I have also uploaded or linked to

Currently:

- I have the video module installed, which allows me to upload videos, but not link to urls.
- I have the video filter module installed, which allows me to link to youtube video urls, but not to urls of mp4 files. (Our client wants to host their videos on adobe-connect.)

I have been searching the internet for a while now, and there doesn't seem to be a one size fits all solution to this problem, so I would also be grateful of any suggestions that solve part or half of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This module https://drupal.org/project/filefield_sources should help you to allow users to give URLs to files.